# How to re-use/replace existing SharePoint Hosted Add-in to SharePoint Framework solution?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-framework

In reference to this article here - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-add-in-retirement-in-mic....

I would like to know what are the options to replace existing SharePoint add-in's using SharePoint Framework and how the transition can be done.

A little background:

We have a SharePoint Hosted Add-in which is developed using knockout.js. Its a form application that does CRUD operations and also has a XAML workflow for approvals. I need assistance in understanding how to re-use the existing add-in and deploying this solution using SharePoint Framework, if it is even possible. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.